# Programmatically added button wont work

Tags: ios, uibutton, programmatically-created

So this is what i have. I have created a button and set it to an action but every time i click the button it crashes the program. Why wont my button work? Thanks in advance.

```
UIButton *currentGamesButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
currentGamesButton.frame = CGRectMake(124,18,72,65);
[currentGamesButton addTarget:self
                       action:@selector(goToCurrentGamesViewController:)
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIImage *currentGamesPNG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CurrentGamesHighlightedState.png"];
[currentGamesButton setBackgroundImage:currentGamesPNG forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:currentGamesButton];
```

Comment: I suspect that it does not find the selector goToCurrentGamesViewController: Can you show the code for this method, including its declaration?

Comment: in the .h: (IBAction) goToCurrentGamesViewController;

Comment: in the .m (IBAction) goToCurrentGamesViewController{

Comment: see my answer below. it applies to your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the method for `goToCurrentGamesViewController` takes no parameters, change this line:

```
[currentGamesButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(goToCurrentGamesViewController:)
```

to:

```
[currentGamesButton addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(goToCurrentGamesViewController)
```

(remove the colon `:` from the method in the selector)

Comment: thanks. that worked out. What kind of parameters can you add to an action? Just curious.

Comment: parameters passed to a methods in a selector can only include an id, which is when the `:` comes into play